# the authentication failed because of missing 'authorization' header

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/{tenantid}", error="invalid_token", error_description="The authentication failed because of missing 'Authorization' header."

statuscode : unauthorized

using    client_id, 
client_secret, 
grant_type, 
resource

[image][image: getting accesstoken]

[image: create certificate]Thanks in advance

[image: error description]

Comment: Which api do you want to call?

Comment: management.azure.com, graph.microsoft.com

Comment: You need to get the access token and add it to the header like this Authorization:Bearer {accesstoken} Take a look at this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Comment: Are using any library or using APIs for authentication

Comment: @Nagarajan.M Have you added the permission and click admin grant button?

Comment: i dont have that much permission. azure from client side. so they created app registration. so when i trying to create DPS certificate from IOT(azure portal) it is showing The authentication failed because of missing 'Authorization' header

Comment: Shouldn't the resource be `https://management.azure.com/` instead of `https://graph.microsoft.com`?

Comment: @GauravMantri Please refer my images (getting access token, create certificate (using accesstoken), error description)

Comment: In your first screenshot, the resource for which you're acquiring the token is `https://graph.microsoft.com`. If your objective is to access Azure Subscription resources, the resource should be either `https://management.core.windows.net/` or `https://management.azure.com`.

Comment: @GauravMantri Using https://management.azure.com, i am getting this             
             error StatusCode: Forbidden, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 445)                           {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client '***' with object id '**' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Devices/provisioningServices/certificates/write' over scope '/subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/**/providers/Microsoft.Devices/provisioningServices/**/certificates/**'."}}

Comment: So i think i dont have permission on this. i need to get permission from my client. Because they are the owner of azure. Right ? @GauravMantri

Comment: @Nagarajan.M Correct, you need to grant a role to the application(at least contributor role to call that api)

Comment: Thanks all of you. Once i get contributor role. i will share my answer with you.

Comment: @Nagarajan.M Do you have any chance to test it?

Comment: No @TonyJu we are going with manual, not with api. you have any experience on CA certificate? i am getting this error - Service Error 401002 CA certificate not found error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [grant Contributor role to your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) and then get access token with resource(https://management.azure.com/).
[image]

Then you will be able to call the api.

[image]

You can also call the api directly by using the try function in api document.
[image]

Comment: could you let me know ? is that permission issue from microsoft graph from app registration?

Comment: @Nagarajan.M Which document did you refer to?

Comment: Please refer my images (getting access token, create certificate (using accesstoken), error description)

Comment: @Nagarajan.M I have tried this api on my side and it works. I will update my answer with the details.

Comment: i am getting this error   StatusCode: Forbidden, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 445)              {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client '' with object id '' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Devices/provisioningServices/certificates/write' over scope '/subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/**/providers/Microsoft.Devices/provisioningServices/**/certificates/*'."}}

Comment: So i think i dont have permission on this. i need to get permission from my client. Because they are the owner of azure. Right ?

Comment: @Nagarajan.M What is your role of this Azure subscription?

Comment: @Nagarajan.M Login Azure portal->All services->click Subscriptions-click the subscription->click Access control. Can you add role assignment?  To add and remove role assignments, you must have:

Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write and Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/delete permissions, such as User Access Administrator or Owner

Answer (score 0):

You can use below piece of code to get token. Then pass this token in header with Bearer key word. for more reference, you can look this links (https://github.com/inzi25/AzureFunctionAPIMBackup)

```
private static async Task<String> GetToken()
        {
            string clientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);

            var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientID, credential);

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed Infaaz, please refer my postman pic. I got accesstoken but using this access token i am getting this error The authentication failed because of missing 'Authorization' header

Comment: ok. Can u able to get sort now by passing in below format, Authorization : Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <access token>

Comment: could you let me know ? is that permission issue from microsoft graph from app registration?

Comment: ok. Still Are u getting error ? Can i get the error message ? By the way which API that u try ...I mean which function ?

Comment: Please refer my images (getting access token, create certificate (using accesstoken), error description)